# Prove $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2} - 3) + n$ is $O(n\lg n)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I just had an exam in my algorithms class and this was a question on it. I was able to craft a solution, but I'm not sure if my proof has errors.

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{n}{2}-3 < n & \forall n > 0 \tag 1\\
&\lg\left(\frac{n}{2}-3\right) < \lg(n)  & \forall n > 0\tag 2\\
&\lg(n) < n & \forall n > 0\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Proceed inductively. Base case usually holds for recursive algorithms as $T(1)$ is $O(1)$ or some constant time.

Assume $T(k) = O(k\lg k)$ for all $k < n$, that is $T(k) \leq ck\lg k$. Then,
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 2T(\frac{n}{2} -3) + n\\
&\leq \left(2c\cdot(\frac{n}{2} -3)\cdot \lg\left(\frac{n}{2} -3\right)\right) + n\\
&= (cn-6c)\cdot \lg(n) + n \quad \text{by (2)}\\
&= cn\lg{n}-6c\lg n + n \\
&\leq cn\lg{n} + n + cn \\ 
&= cn\lg{n} - (-1-c)n \\
&\leq cn\lg{n} \quad\text{for all $c>1$}
\end{align}

Thus, it follows by definition that $T(n) = O(n\lg{n})$

Did I make too many assumptions about the behavior of the inequalities?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Base case usually holds..." doesn't mean anything.

Comment: (2) is wrong for small enough $n$ ($>0$ isn't quite enough).

Comment: "Assume $T(k)=O(k\lg k)$ for $k<n$ doesn't make sense. You have to get into the details of what that big-$O$ notation means, and start your proof there.

Comment: @dfeuer we are told in class that the base case for some discrete function will always break down into a trivial case where it becomes constant time.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm thinking about n-large, but I see how I lost rigor there. I'm wondering if the inequalities hold for n-large. Also, what doesn't make sense of the inductive hypothesis, the definition is directly below it as the first line in the aligned statements.

Comment: Wait, something else about this is very, very wrong. Your condition doesn't make any sense if $n$ is odd!

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not sure what you're referencing.. Can you keep going? I'm trying to understand if the flow through the inequalities holds.

Comment: Neurax, your premise indicates that $T(7)=2T(1/2)+7$. What does $T(1/2)$ mean? If $T$ is a function on the natural numbers (which you pretty much need for induction to work), then there is no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $T(k)\leqslant ck\log(k)$ for every $k\lt n$, for some $n\geqslant30$ and some $c\geqslant2$. Then $T(n)\leqslant c(n-6)\log(n-6)-c(n-6)\log2+n$. In particular, $T(n)\leqslant cn\log(n)-R(n)$ with $R(n)=2(n-6)\log2-n\geqslant.3n-9$ hence $R(n)\geqslant0$ and $T(n)\leqslant cn\log(n)$.

Thus, choosing $c\geqslant\max\{2\}\cup\{T(n)/(n\log n);n\leqslant30\}$ one gets a property $T(n)\leqslant cn\log(n)$ which is hereditary for $n\geqslant30$ and true for $n\leqslant30$. QED.

Comment: About your proof, it is impossible that $T(n)\leqslant cn\lg n+n+cn$ could imply that $T(n)\leqslant cn\lg n$, please check the faulty steps inbetween.

Comment: I'm still puzzled by what things like $T(1/2)$ might mean. Do you have some insight? Is the domain supposed to be restricted to powers of $2$?

Comment: @dfeuer And so am I! (puzzled...) To neglect this aspect seems to be an unfortunate characteristics of the many homework problems in this domain that the site receives. I might even have explained in detail the problem somewhere on MSE (then got lazy...).